# Ways to decrease IntelliJ IDEA ram usage?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ram

I need to make it so IntelliJ idea uses less ram, any tips to make it use less ram?

Comment: In addition to the answer below you can reduce -Xmx in Help | Edit Custom VM Options and restart the IDE. If none of the provided steps helped and you see **abnormal** RAM consumtion (like 10GB), contact JetBrains support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and provide diagnostic details as per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Be aware that all [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s tend to demand much RAM. This includes *IntelliJ*, *NetBeans*, and *Eclipse*. They are not intended to be run on machines with constrained resources.

## Disable plugins

IntelliJ by default has many active plugins.

Use the *Plugins* panel in preferences to examine each one. Deactivate the ones of no use to you.

[See the manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html#required-plugins).

[image]

## Remote access

FYI, if the computer in front of you is constrained but you have access to a more powerful computer remotely, you may want to try the *JetBrains Client* to make use of IntelliJ running remotely on that other machine. See the JetBrains page, [*Remote Development Overview*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/remote-development-overview.html).

I vaguely recall that JetBrains announced a paid service where they would provide an IntelliJ environment in the cloud. You could configure to your liking, paying for CPU cores and memory. I don’t know the current status.

Comment: Thanks but this is not really possible for some people to afford the 'powerful' IDE remotely. They are not cheap.